# Powershell how to compare remote destination with local destination to find differences

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0, robocopy

A few weeks ago,  we began a robocopy transfer of about 8TB of data between site A and site B.

As we prepare for a final cut-over, we'd like to compare the data between both sides to make sure that site B has everything from site A.  I originally tried doing this by mounting the shares as volumes and running the following:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-ChildItem -Recurse I:\directoryAA\directoryAB) -DifferenceObject (Get-ChildItem -Recurse J:\directoraBA\directoryBB) | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\diff.csv'
```

We have a large directory tree with quite a bit of data, and this command never seemed to complete after a week of waiting.  What would be the fastest way for us to compare and find differences between Site A and Site B using powershell?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to elaborate. Do you want to just compare each individual Directory contents? OR did you actually want to compare files to make sure they're the same?

c:\temp\file.txt 0 KB

is not the same as

c:\temp\file.txt 100 KB

...even though the directory contents and paths are the same. See what I mean?  Also Export-CSV is pretty slow. Try getting output on the screen first. And try it with 2 smaller local directories. Once you get it working then you can hit the actual data set.

Comment: Thanks.  What i'm hoping to obtain is a comparison of directory contents to ensure that what exists in site A also exists in site B.  I'm confident that if it exists on both sides, the file will be the same since most of these files have not had changes to them in years.

Comment: So just a thought, have you considered using DFS-R to accomplish this? It seems that it would be a good fit for your use case. 8 TB is a pretty large data set so you may need to adjust the quotas in DFS, but it should do the job. It's built for this kind of thing actually. 

I think you can accomplish what you want in the shell. But I would do it differently. I would use a for each loop and compare each folder by contents on a folder by folder basis.